# Oracle - query failed statements

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a view (or other method) in Oracle, from which I can extract the failed sql statements, which were executed by the user? I tried to check v$sql but, as it turned out, it contains only the successful ones. I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.

Thank You.

Comment: Check this [Link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1369001500346761681)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blaim me if I'm wrong but as far as I understand sql gets logged on shared pool check and statements Laszlo mentioned `select nonexistingcolumn from dual;` failed on semantic check. My answer is you won't find invalid statements in DB.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_sqlproc.htm#TGSQL178